# Error al conectar Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.2.20 a Oracle XE 11.2 en UBUNTU

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo el siguiente error al tratar de conectarme a Oracle XE desde SQL Developer

```
Se ha producido un error al realizar la operación solicitada:

    ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
    ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
    00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
    *Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
               (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
    *Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
               can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
    Código de proveedor 604
```

Solo desde esa app no me puedo conectar, es mas probé la conexión mediente por JBDC y me lo hace de maravillas.

```
package py.conexion;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Conexion {

private static String ORACLE_DRIVER = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

    introducir el código aquí
    protected String host = "127.0.0.1";
    protected String port = "1521";
    protected String dbname = "xe";
    protected String user = "usuario";
    protected String password = "password";


    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("DBAccessOracle");
    private Connection conn;

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(ORACLE_DRIVER);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname; // SERVICE

        System.out.println(url);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        return conn;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Conexion c = new Conexion();
            System.out.println(c.getConnection().getMetaData().getDatabaseMajorVersion());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Una ayuda por favor

Comment: Dices que solo desde esa app no te puedes conectar... pero ¿te puedes conectar con otra desde el mismo equipo? es para verificar que tienes el cliente oracle funcionando. En caso de ser así, ¿que version de cliente oracle es? ¿Un instantclient? ¿Tienes las variables de entorno bien seteadas? Te hará falta el TNS_ADMIN apuntando a la carpeta del cliente donde está el fichero tnsnames.ora y además el NLS_LANG con el valor que necesites para trabajar con tu base de datos

Comment: El problema fue el NLS_LANG. Muchas gracias por el comentario

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para corregir el error que arroja SQL Developer lo que me funcionó después de probar miles de cosas sin ningún éxito fue modificar la configuración que usa:

Debes abrir el archivo

```
[SQL DEVELOPER INSTALATION PATH]\sqldeveloper\bin\sqldeveloper.conf
```

y agregar las siguientes lineas

```
AddVMOption  -Duser.region=us
AddVMOption  -Duser.language=en
```

La region US y el lenguaje EN deben funcionar para cualquier lenguaje de instalación (es el idioma que entiende por defecto el motor).

Espero te sirva!

Comment: Funciona correctamente con el agregado de lineas al "sqldeveloper.conf". Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

set EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES=-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US %EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES%
set JAVA_PROPERTIES=%JAVA_PROPERTIES% %EXTRA_JAVA_PROPERTIES%

EN este archivo .- C:\Users\cjimenez.DGSGIF\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.3.42.170820.0914\DefaultDomain\bin
setDomainEnv.cmd

Comment: Explica tu respuesta para que sea mejor recibida por la comunidad

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo para Responder. Por favor revisa [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida.